# Elegant way to check ArrayList containing Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, equals, contains

I encountered the following problem. I did some research but can't find a satisfying answer, so if this is a duplicate, feel free to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Say i have a CustomClass A. Just 2 parameters, nothing special, no equal-method has been overwritten.

```
A inst1 = new A(5,3);
A inst2 = new A(6,7);
A inst3 = new A(3,5);
```

This creates 3 instances of A, all different.
Now i put them in two Arrays:

```
A[] arr1 = new A[3];
arr1[0] = inst1;
arr1[1] = inst2;
arr1[2] = inst3;

A[] arr2 = new A[3];
arr2[0] = inst1;
arr2[1] = inst2;
arr2[2] = inst3;
```

If i now create an ArrayList and add the arr1

```
ArrayList<A[]> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
arraylist.add(arr1)
```

I expect that arraylist contains arr2.

```
arraylist.contains(arr2) //returns false
```

I wrote a custom method to check, but because ArrayList.contains calls the equal method, i assume there is a more elegant way. I found out, that you can't just overwrite the equals method of Arrays.

custom method:

```
private boolean listContainsAArray(ArrayList<A[]> list, A[] arr){
    int listsize = list.size();
    for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        A[] listelement = list.get(i);
        if((listelement[0]==arr[0])&(listelement[1]==arr[1])&(listelement[2]==arr[2])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have defined `arraylist` as type of `A` and how are you able to add type array??

Comment: Shouldn't be ArrayList<A[]> arraylist??

Comment: you are right, my fault. I edited the question